# C#: Get Linq Object From Key

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL and I'm wondering if there is a short cut to this syntax:

```
using (Model db = new Model())
{
    LinqObj l = db.LinqObj.Where(o => o.ID = id).Single();
}
```

I know I could just create a static method that returns a LinqObj object:

```
public static LinqObj FromID(int id)
{
    using (Model db = new Model())
    {
        return LinqObj l = db.LinqObj.Where(o => o.ID = id).Single();
    }
}
```

Which got me thinking; is there a way to create a constructor that returns the object:

```
LinqObj l = new LinqObj(ID: 7);
```

What is the best way to create an object of a single row in a LINQ to SQL object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a utility method for the LINQ to SQL boilerplate:

```
static T GetObject<T>(Func<Model, T> func)
{
   using(var db = new Model()) return func(db); 
}
```

And then just do this:

```
var l = GetObject(db => db.LinqObj.Single(o => o.ID == id));
```

Comment: Is it really a good idea to encourage people to acquire objects where the DataContext is created behind the scenes?  It seems troublesome since all objects you obtain in this fashion will not really be able to work together; objects must be obtained from the same DataContext to fully interoperate.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use this in a public API but it should be okay for internal/private use. I don't know how the objects are being used in the OP's case but this should be fine for read-only scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing to do is create methods to help create or retrieve the data you need like your static method example. You could possibly extend your class and put logic in the constructor to do some retrieval, but I'm not sure this is a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with:

```
dataContext.LinqObjs.Single(x => x.Id = 23);
```

?  It's very readable, and it obviously properly re-uses your existing DataContext.  It's a bad practice to create a DataContext for every object you get.  It's a pain to manually re-attach them, and if you don't you can't add one object to the container properties of another.